# jQuery Treemap Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the Treemap plugin (http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article40) working with jQuery v1.3.x. The plugin works with jQuery v1.1 and v1.2 but for some reason it fails with the v1.3 base.

This is the browser error "Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: >"

Does anyone know changes occurred between JQuery v1.2 and v1.3 that could cause this?

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 3):

I just fixed this for myself. Change `var cells = $(">",this);` to `var cells = $(this).children();` in getDataFromTable(). I guess this was an old jQuery idiom which is no longer compatible with the latest versions.

I also did a similar replace of the other use of the "greater than" selector at line 50 of the main treemap function, changing it to `var newObj = jQuery(el).children().insertBefore(el);`, but I didn't need that to get the actual treemap working.

Cheers,

Matt